# Typescript - Remove undeclared properties of a class

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, dto

I am trying to create a DTO class. But I am having issues finding a proper way to exclude undeclared properties. So if some one tries to create a DTO class and adds extra properties that are not declared inside the class then those properties should be ignored and not be added.

```
import { IsString, MinLength } from 'class-validator'

export class CreateUserDto {
  @IsString()
    email: string

  @IsString()
  @MinLength(6)
    password: string

  @IsString()
    firstname: string

  @IsString()
    lastname: string

  constructor (payload: any) {
    const dto = Object.assign(this, payload)

    console.log(dto)
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this question depend on `class-validator`? If so you might want to tag it as such so that you will attract people who know about it. If not you might want to remove the apparent dependency from your example code so that you will not deter people who do not know about it.

Comment: For example, one of the overloads is .... `assign<T, U, V>(target: T, source1: U, source2: V): T & U & V`... so the resultant is `T & U & V`, which means anything unique is getting along.. :-)

Comment: if you use class-validator, use the whitelisting feature: https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#whitelisting

Answer (score 0):

For only 4 fields, I'd rather manually type out 4 lines to assign them each, but I guess if you have more DTO's with a lot more fields it could help with a more versatile method.

Here I've used `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries` along with a filter to exclude properties we don't need:

```
const dto = Object.assign(this, Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(payload).filter(([k]) => keys.includes(k))))
```

And `keys` would be something like:

```
["email", ...]
```

You can also make this a function for reusability or even a decorator too.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBA1gUwJ4RgXhgbQEQILYCGAlgDbYA0M2ADgRBAO4gBOAJhVQGZHPRgF4EHbCTpR+g7AF0AsACh5CAB7UWsYKPowAwswQEoCAKoQEzACJQQMAN7yYDmPmIkAhAC4Y0ZkTABzeXtHWnomNg8vKB9-QLlHGG5ecQEECO9fAIU4x01kwTSojNj40EgogFdgK2YYAApaJBIQAlZPAjAkAEpbIPiHUugYVit0GAB5ACMAKwQqgDo6CCI-MFqoAAsiCEpJmfnOZhA8AFEwQoQIWt3ZqDmEM58L+oJG5tZOue4SQ2Za2sw4FJumgAHzwZAQOa+DTlVhPOCdRGdYp9frgCAgEgIOZNPy1YYgZHZBwAX3kZLkQA)